# php.ini and the IIS session state

Tags: php, iis-7

I made a change to my php.ini for the date.timezone settings on a production server to eliminate a ton of php warnings in my php-errors.log file.  I read that I needed to restart IIS.

I had someone tell me "I believe php uses file based session as default and to be honest I don't think anything will happen to you if restart IIS (Other then a delay)."

How can I verify that PHP is configured to use file based sessions?  I looked a the web server and I see a ASP.NET session icon but nothing references PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all PHP installations use files to store sessions. In your php.ini you can see what the settings are. The manual lists all of the [configuration directives](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php), which should be the same for Windows

Comment: I looked at the session variables but don't know enough about php to verify.  Is it session.save_handler?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, should have made that more obvious

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to this site.  I noticed stackoverflow has reputation points.  How do I vote for you to give you great feedback?  :-)

Comment: Actually, see the empty checkmark above that 0 by my response? Click it and that will mark your question answered (which is even better)